# Network onDisconnect() method not working with custom callback

Tags: android, angular, typescript, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to detect changes in the network connection in an Android device, and show a warning when there is no active internet connection.

I was able to add a Network Service to my app and I injected it into the `app.component.ts`. It is my understanding that this will allow the app to detect network changes in any component.

The network changes where detected fine *except at startup*. I currently work around this by just activating/deactivating mobile data, which makes the `onDisconnect()` detect the correct network status.

Now I have another problem, I need to keep a timer of the last message shown (in order to not show too many warnings to the user). When I call a custom method `warningMessage()` inside the callback of `onDisconnect()`, *the method works at startup but not at any other moment*.

This is my Network Service `network.service.ts`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Network } from '@ionic-native/network/ngx';
import { Dialogs } from '@ionic-native/dialogs/ngx';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class NetworkService {

  private deviceConnected:boolean;

  private lastMessage;

  constructor(private network:Network,
              private dialogs:Dialogs
  ) {
  }

  setDeviceConnectionStatus( status:boolean ){ 
    this.deviceConnected = status;
    //this.warningMessage(); I've tried calling my function here
  }

  getDeviceConnectionStatus():boolean{
    return this.deviceConnected;
  }

   /**
   * Method that changes the deviceConnected variable to true or false,
   * according to the actual status. 
   */
  monitorNetwork(){


    this.network.onDisconnect().subscribe( () => {
      
      this.setDeviceConnectionStatus(false);
      console.log('Network available: ', false);
      //this.warningMessage();   // 1st attempt to call function
      
    })

    this.network.onConnect().subscribe( () => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.setDeviceConnectionStatus(true);
        console.log('Network available: ', true);
      }, 2000)
    });
  }
```

And this is the `app.component.ts`

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';
import { AndroidPermissions } from '@ionic-native/android-permissions/ngx';
import { NetworkService } from './network.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(
    private platform: Platform,
    private splashScreen: SplashScreen,
    private statusBar: StatusBar,
    private androidPermissions: AndroidPermissions,
    private networkService: NetworkService
  ) {
    this.initializeApp();
  }

  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.splashScreen.hide();
      this.networkService.monitorNetwork();  // this is where the network service is used
      this.androidPermissions.requestPermissions(
        [
          this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.CAMERA, 
          this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, 
          this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        ]
      );
    });
  }
}
```

I'm currently using ionic 4 and the [network plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/network).

What I've tried:

- Updated all dependencies (ionic and npm)
- Enabled production mode
- Calling the `warningMessage()` method from different places.

Comment: Hi. Did you find any solution?